# How to lock the screen orientation in a service class?

Tags: android, locking, orientation

I have a service class i want to lock the screen orientation from the service class how to do that i can do it in an activity but it is not working on service class

```
public void lockOrientation(){
    int current = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    switch (current) {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        break;
    default:
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    }
}
```

It is giving an error on setRequestedOrientation it is saying to create a method how to solve this problem.

Comment: Services don't use the UI and so have no business interacting with it like this. If your service is somehow intimately tied to your Activity, you need to message your activity to do this work... perhaps through a private broadcast that your activity receives.